# Uneven CPU load distribution

Tags: performance, hardware, cpu-usage

I have a system with uneven CPU load in a odd pattern. It's serving up apache, elastic search, redis, and email.

Here's the `mpstat` output. Notice how %usr for the last 12 cores is well below the top 12.

```
# mpstat -P ALL
Linux 3.5.0-17-generic (<server1>)    02/16/2013      _x86_64_        (24 CPU)

10:21:46 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
10:21:46 PM  all   17.15    0.00    2.20    0.33    0.00    0.09    0.00    0.00   80.23
10:21:46 PM    0   27.34    0.00    4.08    0.56    0.00    0.53    0.00    0.00   67.48
10:21:46 PM    1   24.51    0.00    3.25    0.53    0.00    0.34    0.00    0.00   71.38
10:21:46 PM    2   26.69    0.00    4.20    0.50    0.00    0.24    0.00    0.00   68.36
10:21:46 PM    3   24.38    0.00    3.04    0.70    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00   71.65
10:21:46 PM    4   24.50    0.00    4.04    0.57    0.00    0.15    0.00    0.00   70.74
10:21:46 PM    5   21.75    0.00    2.80    0.74    0.00    0.15    0.00    0.00   74.55
10:21:46 PM    6   28.30    0.00    3.75    0.84    0.00    0.04    0.00    0.00   67.07
10:21:46 PM    7   30.20    0.00    3.94    0.16    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00   65.67
10:21:46 PM    8   30.55    0.00    4.09    0.12    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00   65.21
10:21:46 PM    9   32.66    0.00    3.40    0.09    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00   63.81
10:21:46 PM   10   32.20    0.00    3.57    0.08    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00   64.12
10:21:46 PM   11   32.08    0.00    3.92    0.08    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00   63.88
10:21:46 PM   12    4.53    0.00    0.41    0.34    0.00    0.04    0.00    0.00   94.68
10:21:46 PM   13    9.14    0.00    1.42    0.32    0.00    0.04    0.00    0.00   89.08
10:21:46 PM   14    5.92    0.00    0.70    0.35    0.00    0.06    0.00    0.00   92.97
10:21:46 PM   15    6.14    0.00    0.66    0.35    0.00    0.04    0.00    0.00   92.81
10:21:46 PM   16    7.39    0.00    0.65    0.34    0.00    0.04    0.00    0.00   91.57
10:21:46 PM   17    6.60    0.00    0.83    0.39    0.00    0.05    0.00    0.00   92.13
10:21:46 PM   18    5.49    0.00    0.54    0.30    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   93.65
10:21:46 PM   19    6.78    0.00    0.88    0.21    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   92.12
10:21:46 PM   20    6.17    0.00    0.58    0.11    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   93.13
10:21:46 PM   21    5.78    0.00    0.82    0.10    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   93.29
10:21:46 PM   22    6.29    0.00    0.60    0.10    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   93.00
10:21:46 PM   23    6.18    0.00    0.61    0.10    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   93.10
```

I have another system, a database server running MySQL, which shows an even distribution.

```
# mpstat -P ALL
Linux 3.5.0-17-generic (<server2>)    02/16/2013      _x86_64_        (32 CPU)

10:27:57 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
10:27:57 PM  all    0.77    0.00    0.07    0.68    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.47
10:27:57 PM    0    2.31    0.00    0.19    1.86    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   95.63
10:27:57 PM    1    1.73    0.00    0.17    1.87    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   96.21
10:27:57 PM    2    2.62    0.00    0.25    2.51    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   94.62
10:27:57 PM    3    1.60    0.00    0.17    1.99    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   96.23
10:27:57 PM    4    1.86    0.00    0.16    1.84    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   96.13
10:27:57 PM    5    2.30    0.00    0.25    2.45    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   94.99
10:27:57 PM    6    2.05    0.00    0.20    1.89    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   95.86
10:27:57 PM    7    2.13    0.00    0.20    2.31    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   95.36
10:27:57 PM    8    0.82    0.00    0.11    4.05    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00   94.99
10:27:57 PM    9    0.70    0.00    0.18    0.06    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.06
10:27:57 PM   10    0.18    0.00    0.04    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.77
10:27:57 PM   11    0.20    0.00    0.01    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.78
10:27:57 PM   12    0.13    0.00    0.01    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.86
10:27:57 PM   13    0.04    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.95
10:27:57 PM   14    0.03    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.97
10:27:57 PM   15    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.97
10:27:57 PM   16    0.05    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.94
10:27:57 PM   17    0.41    0.00    0.10    0.04    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.45
10:27:57 PM   18    2.78    0.00    0.06    0.14    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.01
10:27:57 PM   19    1.19    0.00    0.08    0.19    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.53
10:27:57 PM   20    0.48    0.00    0.04    0.30    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.17
10:27:57 PM   21    0.70    0.00    0.03    0.16    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.11
10:27:57 PM   22    0.08    0.00    0.01    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.90
10:27:57 PM   23    0.30    0.00    0.02    0.06    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.62
10:27:57 PM   24    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
10:27:57 PM   25    0.04    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.94
10:27:57 PM   26    0.06    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.93
10:27:57 PM   27    0.01    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.98
10:27:57 PM   28    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.99
10:27:57 PM   29    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
10:27:57 PM   30    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
10:27:57 PM   31    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.99
```

Both are dedicated systems running Ubuntu 12.10 (not virtual).

I've thought and read up about setting nice, taskset, or trying to tweak the scheduler but I don't want to make any rash decisions. Also, this system isn't performing "bad" per-se, I just want to ensure all cores are being utilized properly.

Let me know if I can provide additional information. Any suggestions to even the CPU load on "server1" are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem until some cores hit 100% and others don't (i.e. in the statistics you've shown us, there's nothing that would suggest that the uneven distribution is negatively affecting the performance). In your case, you probably have quite a few processes that distribute evenly, resulting in a base load of 6-10% on each core, and then ~12 more threads that require 10-20% of a core *each*. You can't split a single process/thread between cores.